# Check Facebook login status: Client side vs Server side

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

In the website that I am building, I need to check whether or not the user is logged in to facebook. I have two possibilities. I can either do it on the server side, using PHP code like following:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId'  => _FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                'secret' => _FACEBOOK_SECRET,
                'cookie' => true));
$me = $facebook->api("/me");
if (isset($me["id"]) {
    // User is logged in.
} else {
    // User is not logged in.
}
```

Alternatively, I can do it on the client side, using javascript like following:

```
FB.getSession();
if (session != null) {
    // User is logged in.
} else {
    // User is not logged in
}
```

I am wondering what are the pros and cons of the two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your "server-side" approach is not correct. As long as you are using the PHP-SDK I recommend you follow the approach in the [example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) attached with the library (checking for session before making graph calls `$facebook->getSession();`.
2. You need to "understand" what you actually "need"!
   Checking if a user is "*logged-in to Facebook*" **does not** mean that he is "*connected to your application/website*"

I suggest you read the [Facebook Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/) one more time to better understand the API.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to point out that the JavaScript alternative you show is deprecated and no longer works, the docs link (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getSession/) redirects to the new getAuthSession() function for handling OAuth2

> As of December 13th, 2011, the JavaScript SDK now only supports OAuth 2.0 for authentication. The 
>   ability to enable OAuth 2.0 in the JS SDK was first introduced in July. All apps were given until 
>   October 1, 2011 to test and migrate. With this change, please ensure that you are using 
>   FB.getAuthResponse to obtain the access token instead of FB.getSession. Read more about the specific 
>   changes her

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main difference, is that on the client side, the connection is made between the client and facebook. On the server side, it's between your server and facebook. So the load of your server can get high if you do everything on the server side.